# How to stop ggplotly boxplots to overlap with each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have this code that produces the graph below. I don't like the way that the boxplots overlap for each of the different x axis variables. This is my code...

```
women_income_final_plot <- ggplot(women_income_final, aes(x = 
          reorder(factor(income_group), mean_fin_in), y = mean_fin_in, fill = 
factor(year))) + geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm') +
  labs(
    x = 'Income Groups -',
    y = 'Financial Inclusion Index Score -',
    title = 'Financial Inclusion Index Scores by Income Group -',
    subtitle = 'Women Population | 2017 vs 2021',
    caption = 'Data: Global Findex Database, The World Bank',
    fill = 'Year -'
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, color = 'black')) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'black'))

ggplotly(women_income_final_plot)
```

Can someone please provide a solution on how to fix this?[image]